# Firebase functions failing to start with Nuxt3 ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: node.js, firebase, es6-modules, firebase-tools, nuxtjs3

I am trying to run my nuxt3 application on the firebase emulator on my local machine, but its, however, failing with the following error

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
> <my_project_dir>.output\server\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js
> from
> <my_project_dir>.output\server\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\common\providers\identity.js
> not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in
> C:\Users\Christian\vscode\nuxt3-starter.output\server\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\common\providers\identity.js
> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

I am using the following command to build my application

> npx cross-env NITRO_PRESET=firebase npm run build

My nuxt3 build version is v3.0.0-rc.1-27510703.46ecbc5 and my firebase library versions are

> "firebase-admin": "^10.1.0",  "firebase-functions": "^3.20.0",
> "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"